# Can I solve for all integer solutions of this diophantine equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I do not know much about this subject, but this problem is bothering me.

$$
x + 33y = 2399
$$

How can I find the possible integer values of x and y? I know there are two solutions, which I discovered by brute force. I just want to know if it's possible to find them without brute force.

Thanks.

edit: I tried to learn how to solve these types of equations, and I read they are solvable if gcd(a, b) can divide c. gcb(1, 33) is 1, and 1 divides 2399... Any insight?

Comment: you must determine the region of x, at least

Comment: Okay, I know there are *at least* two solutions. Let's say x is in [50 100] then.

Comment: @AndrePena http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html
Use the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Does it work if the gcd is 1?

Comment: Any integer value of $y$ may be used, and then $x=2399-33y$.  If you impose inequality restrictions on one variable, this will limit the number of solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, if both x *and* y are in [50 100]. For example, one solution is x = 89, y = 70...

Comment: @Cardinal The issue is that this is about Diophantine equations. You want integer solutions only. The solution set is still infinite, but not in the way you are implying.

Comment: If I graph it and try to find solutions, I am essentially using brute force. (trying every integer in the range)

Comment: @Terra Hyde I don't understand how to use the Euclidean algorithm if one of the terms = 1. that is, a = 1, b = 33...

Comment: @AndréPeña Set up the thing like this: $50\leq2399-33y \leq100$ and solve that inequality. For other ranges, use the respective endpoints.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about that. I realised a moment ago that the EA will fail for this one.

Comment: In terms of $(x,y)$ being integers one set of solutions is $(x_{n}, y_{n}) = (33n+23, 72-n)$ for $0 \leq n \leq 72$

Comment: @TerraHyde I knew I was doing something absolutely stupid.

Comment: @Leucippus How did you find that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation
The discussion at this section of the article discusses a method for finding similarly structured solutions.

Comment: @AndréPeña what is the best solution ? i mean what answer could be the best ? for example bigger y value, ... whatever or  the lower x value ? i think you must shrink the solution set !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of solution is as follows.

The equation $x + 33 y = 2399$ can be seen to be satisfied by:
\begin{align}
2399 &= 23 + 33 \cdot 72 \\
&= (1 \cdot 33 + 23) + 33 \cdot 71 \\
&= (2\cdot 33 + 23) + 33 \cdot 70 \\
&= \cdots
\end{align}
This pattern yields a set of solutions $(x_{n}, y_{n})$ in the form
\begin{align}
(x_{n}, y_{n}) = (33\, n + 23, 72 - n)  \hspace{10mm} 0 \leq n \leq 72.
\end{align}

---

A second method is as follows.

Let $x = u^{2} + 22$ and $y = 72 - v^{2}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
u^{2} - 33 \, v^{2} = 1.
\end{align}
This is a standard Pell equation and has the solution set
\begin{align}
u_{n} &= \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ (23 + 4 \sqrt{33})^{n} + (23 - 4 \sqrt{33})^{n} \right] \\
v_{n} &= \frac{1}{2 \, \sqrt{33}} \, \left[ (23 + 4 \sqrt{33})^{n} - (23 - 4 \sqrt{33})^{n} \right]
\end{align}
For reference see [MathWorld Pell equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html). Squaring these values one may obtain the desired set of $(x,y)$ solutions in the form $(x_{n}, y_{n}) = (u_{n}^{2} + 22, 72 - v_{n}^{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to notice about this equation is that for any integer value of $y$, there is an integer value of $x$ that solves the equation.  If we set $y$ to some integer $n$, then the corresponding value of $x$ is $2399-33n.$ Hence the set of integer solutions consists of ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)=(2399-33n,n).$

Note that if we set $n$ to $72-t$ we get the equivalent parameterization, $(33t+23,72-t),$ recovering an earlier answer.